# Can we flag a question that belongs on Quant.SE?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/91377/whats-the-method-to-find-an-initial-equilibrium-benchmark-portfolio-for-black-l) doesn't appear to be about personal finance, accounting or economics. I thought it belonged on [Quant.SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/) but the only option under "belongs on another site" is for here on Money.Meta.

I see a fair number of questions that probably should go on Law.SE, too. Should "belongs on another site" be so tightly restricted?